# How can I GRANT permissions to a user?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have an database `projeto` and a user `USUARIO`. What I should do to give `USUARIO` access to `projeto`?

I tried:

```
GRANT ALL ON projeto TO USUARIO
```

but I get the following error:

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1     
Cannot find the object 'projeto', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

I am using the `sa` account.

Comment: Error msg : You can not 'find' the object 'project', because it does not exist or you do not have permission...

Comment: I created a database with that name and it aprece the list of databases.

Comment: The homework tag is not to be used any longer.

Comment: which version of SQL Server you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be a solution?

"object_name is the name of an database object like TABLE, VIEW, STORED PROC and SEQUENCE"

Maybe you are trying to give permissions to database and `GRANT` does not accept database name as `object_name`. I never tried giving permissions on database so I'm not sure if that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after creating a user on that database (not just the database instance):

```
USE projeto
CREATE USER USUARIO  FOR LOGIN USUARIO
```

The above links the existing login (database instance user) USUARIO to a new user on the projeto database.

After this you can further extend permissions by using the GRANT command on USUARIO, as you now have this user in your database.

Answer (score 0):

This erros means that SQLServer could not find an object named `"Projeto"`... certify that there's a database named `"Projeto"`... maybe you written it wrong... to check it run this query `"Select * from sys.databases"` and for your "grant" question... here's the official Microsoft documentation for the Grant command http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx

Comment: I have one database Projeto

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to grant all permissions on the Projeto database, add them to the db_owner role within that database. That is:

```
use [Projeto];
create user [usario]
exec sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db_owner', @membername = 'usario';
```